# How can I use a post request with Retrofit to deliver data in parameters?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, retrofit

I designed an API that sends data in parameters, however retrofit prevents us from sending data in parameters through a post request. Is there a way to send data in parameters through a post request with retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

Reference:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/")
Call<ResponseBody> example(
    @Field("name") String name,
    @Field("occupation") String occupation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Pojo/Data class for your desired parameters and Then you can make an object by passing all your parameter. Then you can send data through post by using **@Body** tag like:

```
 @POST("/")
 Call<ResponseType> send(@Body Data data)
```

Comment: But the data in my Post API is passed in the query parameters rather than the body.

Comment: That's not true you can pass data as a Body also. I do have tried it by passing data via body.